# How do I prevent my dwarf from getting stuck on the wrong side of a wall?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I dig my way to a small pool and flood an area to use as a farm. Now I'm told I want to wall it up before it rains and floods my fortress. I build a wall, but the dude who comes and builds it gets trapped on the wrong side of the wall. What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build(<kbd>b</kbd>-><kbd>C</kbd>-><kbd>w</kbd>) a wall on the side you don't want your dwarves trapped on, but suspend the construction before it's built(<kbd>q</kbd>-><kbd>s</kbd>). Then when the original wall is done, cancel the suspended wall(<kbd>q</kbd>-><kbd>x</kbd>).

Comment: Or, do as I actually did and just remove and rebuild the wall until the guy ends up on the right side...

Answer (score 2):

the other approach is to plan your wall placements according to work orders. Your dwarfs will always want to stand next to the wall in this order: Top, Left, Right, Bottom. So. Build your top left walls first. all the other walls will be built from the inside the way you would hope.